# Let $f: W\to W$ be a linear transformation, show that $f$ is injective iff $f^*$ is surjective

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f: W\to W$ be a linear transformation on an inner product space $W$ with finite dimension. Show that $f$ is injective iff $f^*$ is surjective.

I was wondering if there's a quick and efficient way to prove this?

Answer (score 2):

> Hint: $$\operatorname{range}f^*=(\text{null f})^\perp $$

**Added**:

If $f$ is injective, then $\text{null} \;f=\{0\}$. So $\operatorname{range}f^*=(\{0\})^\perp=W$, so $f^*$ is surjective

On the other hand, if  $f^*$ is surjective, then $\operatorname{range}f^*=W=(\operatorname{null}f)^\perp$. Consequently $\operatorname{null}f=W^\perp=\{0\}$ and so $f$ is injective

Comment: Why downvote ? Whats wrong?

Comment: Wasn't me lol, someone else downvoted.

Comment: could you provide some more direction for the question if possible? more than just a short hint? :)

Comment: I edit my answer. See that!